# How to use different interaction protocols between microservices and to connect API Gateway?

Tags: node.js, api, rest, microservices, grpc

I am building my first educational microservices project right now.

All of the services are talking to clients via REST. Also, I wanted to get to know the gRPC protocol, so I tried to find ways my services can talk to each other using gRPC and to API Gateway via REST.

To have a good practice, I used different frameworks on different services - Express, Nest, Koa and no one of them can't expose API in different ways simultaneously (as far I know).

So is it possible? Or my architecture should be based on one interaction technology only? How can I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Vlad, not sure what you mean with “can’t expose API in different ways” ... what exactly do you mean by that. Maybe than it would be easier to answer your question. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are several ways I could do it.
Firstly, NestJS can create "hybrid" applications, that can provide both REST and gRPC (connectMicrocervice) API the same time.
Secondly, for those frameworks that can't do that, the solution is to use gRPC to HTTP JSON transcoder (grpc ecosystem has some:
https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-httpjson-transcoding)

So, the question is answered)

Thanx Sebastian Hildebrandt for your attention.